# Misssing revisions in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am observing strange behaviour with TortoiseSVN. Some recent commits are missing from Show Log dialog. Project structure is a usual one:

```
/project/trunk
/project/branches
```

Last few days I have been modifying `/project/trunk/a.txt`.
Show Log for `/project/trunk` does not show some commits but shows others.
Show Log for `/project` shows all revisions.

Other people on the team do not observe this behavior. They have older versions of TortoiseSVN.

Is it a bug?

TortoiseSVN 1.8.4, Build 24972 - 64 Bit.
Subversion version 1.6.11

Comment: Do you mean that your co-workers see commits to `/project/branches` when they request the log for `/project/trunk`? Then I'd say their older TortoiseSVN versions had a bug that's already been fixed in yours :-?

Comment: BTW, TortoiseSVN 1.8.x uses Subversion 1.8; it won't work with 1.6 working copies.

Comment: @Alvaro No. They see commits to `/project/trunk` that I do not see. Working copies had been upgraded to 1.8 format.

Comment: Please check whether you're using the same filters and you've ticked the same checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rare, but occasionally it's possible for the log cache to be come corrupted.
You can either force a refresh of the log cache by hitting `Ctrl+F5` in the log dialog, or go to the `settings dialog, saved data` and hit the `clear` button there to clear the cache.
After that, show the log again and it will be ok.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it didn't help. What did the job was deleting Log caches in Log Caching -> Cached Repositories. Many thanks.